# JavaScript trigger function on event from a script, not explicitly from html

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm making a registration form ATM, I have it like I want it so far except the excess JavaScript code to check the values real-time (`onmouseover`, `onmouseout`, `onblur` etc.).
A small sample:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="name"
               onmouseover="fieldSelected('name', '', 3);"
               onmouseout="checkValue('name', '', 3);">
            Enter your name:
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"
               id="name"
               name="name"
               onmouseover="fieldSelected('name', '', 3);"
               onmouseout="checkValue('name', '', 3);"
               onblur="checkValue('name', '', 3);">
    </td>
</tr>
```

`fieldSelected` makes the field background yellow if the value of the specified element (first parameter) matches the second parameter (default value) or is shorter than third parameter.

You `mouseover` the label or the input field and it changes the bg first to yellow, then to red (since you didn't input anything).
`checkValue` changes the field background to either red or green depending on the value (same parameters).
You enter something in the input field, switch to another field and it changes the background color.

Now, as you will probably notice, there's a LOT of JavaScript function calls right there (5 per each input/select field). It would be great if someone would know a way to attach those event triggers from another place (I don't usually code this dirty), not directly in the form like this and preferably to multiple IDs at once. I have jQuery here, but I'm really no expert in JavaScript.

Or maybe there's a simpler way to do this? I want that the field background color changes on all those events for maximum interactivity. Sure, it's nothing much when all the data goes to the server side but I just want it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest using jQuery, at which point registration of events for your entire page can become:

```
function over(ev) {
    var _for = $(ev.target).closest('tr').find('label').attr('for');
    fieldSelected(_for, '', 3)
};

function out(ev) {
    var _for = $(ev.target).closest('tr').find('label').attr('for');
    checkValue(_for, '', 3)
};

$('table').live('hover', over, out).blur(out);
```

NB: this assumes that every input element and its associated label are in a table row of their own.

http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/XdzeX/

I created a slightly longer version which makes no assumptions about the table layout at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/T6vvN/

```
function handler(ev) {
    // check which field (or label) is being hovered over
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'LABEL') {
        var _for = $(ev.target).attr('for');
    } else {
        var _for = ev.target.name;
    }

    // do event type checking to decide which function to call
    if (ev.type === 'mouseout' || ev.type === 'blur') {
        checkValue(_for, '', 3);
    } else if (ev.type === 'mouseover') {
        fieldSelected(_for, '', 3);
    }        
};

$('label, input').live('hover blur', handler);
```

Comment: somehow it doesn't work... http://jsfiddle.net/XdzeX/6/
really nice website though :)

Comment: it _mostly_ works (see rev #7) - you had the wrong parameter names in your two functions.  I'm not seeing any red, yet, though.

Comment: this works in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T6vvN/8/
will see what happens on the real site.

Comment: slight problem - if you type in that field while cursor is away, the color won't change until you hover over.

Comment: so you need to register the `change` (and/or `keydown`) handler on the field too

Comment: Hmm... it doesn't alert on labels, only on inputs/selects. Can that be fixed? If it can, that would probably be all I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

you can use function "addEventListener" to add event to individual fields on form

```
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){ fieldSelected('name','',3)},false);
```

Google addEventListener for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can do away with the inlining:

```
var input_element = document.getElementById('name');

input_element.onmouseover = function(){
       fieldSelected('name', '', 3);
};

input_element.onmouseout = function(){
       checkValue('name', '', 3);
};
//etcetera
```

And then you can assign other elements in the same manner

Comment: no you can't - that'll evaluate `fieldSelected(...)` immediately and assign the (duff) result to the callback!

Comment: @Alnitak! ahh true, one second

Comment: I tried it like this:
var input_name = register.elements['name'];

input_name.onmouseover = function(){
       fieldSelected('name', '', 3);
};

input_name.onmouseout = function(){
       checkValue('name', '', 3);
};

input_name.onblur = function(){
       checkValue('name', '', 3);
};
didn't work...      register=name of form.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the event handlers to a container and use the `event` object to figure out which input it originated from.

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#events

Comment: Unfortunately that's way too little info for me... How do you attach an event handler to DIV and how do you know which event was triggered and from which input/label field?

Comment: works for single fields in fiddle, but I have: div>form>table>tr>td>table>tr>td label + td input and no reaction... I would have loved if that would've worked.

Comment: Try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/Bxx6C/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/Bxx6C/2/). But, why are you embedding the fields in two tables?

Comment: table with two separate columns, each column has another two connected columns (label+input). I know it could be done some other way (probably even just 4 columns would do) but unfortunately I didn't write it and I'm being rushed all the time so if I try to make it really perfect... well, I don't wanna hear that bs.